# get resource raw & drawable from name in recycle view using cardview

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-resources, android-recyclerview

hello i try all solution of getting resource image and audio file from resource folder but nothing show.
this is code in Adapter
if you want   to go to line direct Ctrl+f /* == My probleme is here == */
and thank you first. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n01NV.png)

Answer (score 0):

do like this:

```
MediaPlayer myMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.audio_1_10);
```

in many cases you do not need to find a path to your resources and store them into variables to use them as long as you want to use them without changing them.

also you can apply the same for your images provide resource id directly into setImageResource method.

Comment: your code its ok, but the problem is i get data from json file so audio_1_10= "audio_"+id+"_"+anotherID